# Regex with long HTML strings and <wbr>

Tags: html, regex, wbr

I just found the `<wbr>` element ([link](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html)) which basically lets specific an area where a break could apply if needed.

Basically I'd like to implement it in my apps, to prevent breaking the layout due a comment in a blog with too many letters or signs.

The problem is: it has to be HTML compatible, so `averylongmadeupandunnecesaryunspacedword` might break apart each 25 characters but it won't break a link `<a href="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=averylongandunnecesarywordingoogle&aq=f&aql=&aqi=&oq=">link</a>`.

Comment: Adding the tags regex and html together should automatically add a warning link to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I know it's kind of pointless to try to parse HTML, but then again, what's the other option? Using a parser just to replace a little string that has a lot of characters?

Comment: `<wbr>` is for human-facing text. That is you use it in your example where you currently have `link`, not where you currently have `averylongandunnecesarywordingoogle` - that's a URL the user doesn't see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using CSS? The **word-wrap** property is supported in IE, Safari, and FireFox 3.5

```
/* example */
.comments { word-wrap: break-word }
```

Also, **<wbr>** [isn't supported on IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) :(